# ID Generator using a class

Tags: python, class, methods

I'm writing a program that takes an entry of 3 names and outputs it with 4 random numbers as an ID.

Sample:

```
First name: James
Middle name: Earl
Last name: Jones
```

Output:

```
Your ID is: JEJ2953
```

What I've got keeps redirecting by saying `Student.enter_name` needs an argument (self).  So I put (self) in there and it says "self is not defined."  I'm going insane.  I'm taking a class that's slightly beyond my abilities.

Here's what I've got:

```
class Student(object):
  """Each student"""
  def __init__(self, firstName, midName, lastName):
    self.firstName = None
    self.midName = None
    self.lastName = None

  def enter_name(self):
    input('First Name: ')
    input('Middle Name: ')
    input('Last Name: ')

  def generate_euid(self):
    import random
    name = self.firstName[0], self.midName[0], self.lastName[0]
    inits = "".join(name)
    for x in range(1):
      print('Your EUID: ', inits + str(random.randint(1000,9999)))

user = Student.enter_name(self)
user = Student.generate_euid()
```

Comment: You should create an instance of the `Student` class, then call it's method. just like `user = Student()`, then call `user.enter_name()`. But it's not a good design style to put a request in an entity.

Answer (score 0):

Is this ?

```
class Student(object):
  """Each student"""
  def __init__(self,):
    self.firstName = None
    self.midName = None
    self.lastName = None

  def enter_name(self):
    self.firstName =input('First Name:')
    self.midName =input('Middle Name:')
    self.lastName =input('Last Name:')

  def generate_euid(self):
    import random
    name = (self.firstName,self.midName,self.lastName)
    inti=''.join(name)
    print('Your EUID: ', inti + str(random.randint(1000,9999)))

x=Student()
x.enter_name()
x.generate_euid()
```

Comment: THANK YOU.  This worked perfectly.  This course I'm taking literally went from "Hello World!" to classes within 4 meetings.

Answer (score 0):

This class is simply a template that specifies what a student should look like; it holds no information about any particular student itself. In order for that to happen, you have to *instantiate* the class -- this can be done by writing, say, `user = Student('John', 'Foo', 'Bar')` (matching the parameters in your `__init__` constructor); this creates an object of type Student, referred to as an 'instance' of the Student class.

Once you have an instance like `user` above, you can call any function bound to it (referred to as an instance method) and it will automatically be passed its own `self` parameter. From here, you will be able to access and modify the variables you've defined on `self` in the `__init__` method.

This is also the reason you can't write `Student.instance_method()`; since the `Student` class is a template rather than a concrete instance, it has no concept of 'itself' to refer to, and so it won't be able to pass `self` to the methods that need it without first being instantiated. (And of course, there is no variable `self` by default, so Python won't know what `self` is when when you try writing `user = Student.enter_name(self)` from the global scope. This is what results in the not-defined error)

Two things to note:

1. There *are* certain methods, namely static methods and class methods, which do not need a `self` parameter and so can be called from the class; these have their own purposes and are probably out of the scope of this question, but in short:

   - Class methods are passed a reference to the uninstantiated class rather than a variable, usually for the purpose of creating an instance of the class from within it. As an example, you could define your enter_name method like so (wonky list codeblock, excuse me):
     `` class Student:
       # ...
       @classmethod
       def enter_name(cls): # cls is the class, ie `Student`
           firstName = input('First name: ')
           # ditto for middleName and lastName
           return cls(firstName, middleName, lastName) ``

     ...and this will do the job of instantiating for you, but from a method encapsulated within the Student class. You can call this as `student_variable = Student.enter_name()`, which is slightly easier to read than if it were a random global function creating Students. (And in fact much better practice than doing the job of instantiating from within an instance!)
   - Static methods, the other kind of method that doesn't take `self`, are essentially regular functions -- they are passed no automagic first parameter -- but they are useful for wrapping 'utility functions' to do with a class' regular methods within the class itself.
2. Your `enter_name()` method actually does nothing at present! For it to be effective you must assign the inputs' return values to `self.firstName`, `self.middleName`, and `self.lastName` in order to actually remember them, after which you can use these variables in your other method(s) like `generate_euid`. Same goes for your `__init__` method; you take variables, `(firstName, midName, lastName)`, but you then do nothing with them, in effect throwing them away.

Here is a full example if the above was unclear:

```
class Student(object):
  """Describes a student"""
  def __init__(self, firstName, midName, lastName):
    self.firstName = firstName
    self.midName = midName
    self.lastName = lastName

  @classmethod # marks the below function as a class method
  def enter_name(cls):
    first = input('First Name: ')
    mid = input('Middle Name: ')
    last = input('Last Name: ')
    return cls(first, mid, last)

  def generate_euid(self):
    import random
    name = self.firstName[0], self.midName[0], self.lastName[0]
    inits = "".join(name)
    for x in range(1):
      print('Your EUID: ', inits + str(random.randint(1000,9999)))
```

```
>>> user0 = Student.enter_name()
First Name: John
Middle Name: Foo
Last Name: Bar
>>> user0.generate_euid()
Your EUID:  JFB4979
>>> user1 = Student('Kate', 'Foo', 'Bar')
>>> user1.generate_euid()
Your EUID:  KFB2855
```

Comment: A lesson AND an answer.  Thank you.  I wish the teaching staff could explain it that visually.

Comment: @ArchivistG No problem! Should also make note of some style stuff for future reference -- `generate_euid()` would be much better with a final line `return inits + str(...)` instead of a `print()`, because returning it affords you flexibility in what you do with the data: you can write, for instance, `print(Your EUID: ', user.generate_euid())` from the outside without affecting the function's return value. Less-important: `import random` should be at the top of the file (for clarity/transparency), and [PEP8](https://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008) suggests snake_case over camelCase for var names!

Comment: That makes sense!  And I made the mistake of taking a short, quick course on Java from LYNDA before starting this class.  camelCase got in my head.